# Doing Something When Enter Key Pressed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement cheat section to my little game. So basically it will be like this:

-User presses enter(or some other button) during the game
-A box opens
-User enters a text
-Cheat activates

Should I add the code inside to form_load function or somewhere else?

I found some codes but they didn't work. For example

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("asd");
            }
```

When I click `Shift` button nothings happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override ProcessCmdKey() in your Forms code like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asd");
            return true; // optionally suppress further processing of the enter key by other controls on the form
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```

This does **NOT** require KeyPreview to be set to true.

Comment: Nice workaround... but I'm still wondering how @JayGatsby managed to make the _normal_ solution to be unresponsive ;-]

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event of your Form:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
           // ...        
      }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happens. Should I call this function from somewhere?

Comment: you need to subscribe the event, `this.KeyDown += Form_KeyDown;` put this into form load event

Comment: I added messagebox.Show event in if statment. I added this.Keydown.. code to my form load event. When I press enter first button on form clicks. I changed Enter with Shift still nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the [`Form.KeyPreview Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

Either in the designer or in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyPreview = true;
}
```

Becasue there is no full answer I present the complete code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPreview = true;
        // Full syntax in case you're using some older Visual Studio.
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asdf");
        }
    }
}
```

@Selman22's suggestion won't work without `KeyPreview` and mine won't of course work without the event handler.

Comment: Ok, then you have to tell us more about your code/design beceause it should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Go with the [Keyboard class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard(v=vs.110).aspx).

You will not need to subscribe to any events, and can use it at any time, although you need to set Focusable=true for certain UI container types, read the help text.

Comment: I think it's about `WinForms` and I couldn't figure out a way to use the `Keyboard` class out of `WPF` context. Can you show a sample if you have any?

Comment: I missed that (winForms). But given that, I bet there is some .dll call that is a lot easier. Sorry, I haven't written any winforms code since the 60's (maybe a little later but not much).